# Why the java sessions are not ending once the cronjob has been executed in AIX OS

Tags: java, linux, bash, cron, aix

I have set a crontab for execute a java service in every 8 hours in AIX(7.1) operating system. Once the crontab has done the job, the JAVA service should be end. This cronjob is working properly. But java service has not been closing its session at the end. Also this java service takes 3-4 hours to process the files.

Java sessions are accumulating day by day and eventually it leads to idle the application server.

***Java Version 1.8

AIX 7.1***

Crontab entry:

```
00 8 * * * cd /ibl/qnb/uat/app/adm/ADM_AUTOMATE_SERV && ./RUN.sh > /ibl/qnb/uat/logs/adm/ADM_AUTOMATE_SERV/run.log
```

If I execute the above statement manually, cronjob runs properly and closing the session at the end.

RUN.sh file:

```
/usr/java8_64/bin/java -Xmx1024m -jar ADM_AUTOMATE_SERV.jar
```

Below are the java sessions still running in the application server. Please have a look and advise  what I'm going wrong?

[image: Total java sessions running currently]

Highly appreciate your time and efforts for this matter.

Comment: All Linux questions must be related to programming; those that aren't will be closed. Use this tag only if your question relates to programming using Linux APIs or Linux-specific behavior, not just because you happen to run your code on Linux. If you need Linux support you can try https://unix.stackexchange.com or the specific Linux distribution's Stack Exchange site like https://askubuntu.com or https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I agree with your point, But those platforms do not allow to post  images, because my reputations points are low.

Comment: There's no way for us to give you an answer without access to the java source. Is there a STOP.sh script there? Does RUN.sh accept any optional arguments?

Comment: We are not using STOP.sh file here because if this service executed manually it will end up once the process done. It should not running in the background. Also this RUN.sh file does not accept additional arguments.
`

Comment: @glennjackman I know it's little tricky here to come up with a solution since no access. By the way, I have noticed, according to the ps list, this service should stuck 3 times per day. But in somedays it had ended up releasing the session properly. So It looks like an issue with the Java service probably. Appreciate your suggestion also

Comment: I vote for closing this question since it's already here: https://serverfault.com/questions/1097895/why-this-java-processes-are-not-ending-once-cronjob-has-executed-in-the-aix-serv. I added my answer there.